# JavaFX and Compiling the HelloWorld with Ant

Tags: ant, javafx

I'm following along with the tutorial at [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html#CHDFHGDE) and am getting this error message when I try to run the jar file output after the code is compiled.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

To setup a java development environment, I went to oracle and downloaded their [Java SE Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and dropped it into `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45` and then pointed to it in the build.xml file as was indicated.

In following the tutorial, I have a project folder with the following code/script:

(example/src/HelloWorld.java)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(example/build.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<project name="JavaFX Hello World Example" default="default" basedir="."
  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

  <property name="JAVA_HOME" value="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45"/>
  <property name="build.src.dir" value="src"/>
  <property name="build.classes.dir" value="classes"/>
  <property name="build.dist.dir" value="dist"/>

  <target name="default" depends="clean,compile">

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
      uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
      classpath="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>

      <fx:application id="HelloWorldID"
        name="JavaFXHelloWorldApp"
        mainClass="HelloWorld"/>

      <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="${build.dist.dir}" includes="HelloWorld.jar"/>
      </fx:resources>

      <fx:jar destfile="${build.dist.dir}/HelloWorld.jar">
        <fx:application refid="HelloWorldID"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
      </fx:jar>

      <fx:deploy width="300" height="250"
        outdir="." embedJNLP="true"
        outfile="helloworld">

        <fx:application refId="HelloWorldID"/>

        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <fx:info title="JavaFX Hello World Application"
          vendor="Oracle Corporation"/>

      </fx:deploy>

  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dist.dir}"/>

    <delete>
      <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" includes="**/*"/>
      <fileset dir="${build.dist.dir}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>

  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="clean">

    <javac includeantruntime="false"
      srcdir="${build.src.dir}"
      destdir="${build.classes.dir}"
      fork="yes"
      executable="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac"
      source="1.8"
      debug="on">
    </javac>
  </target>

</project>
```

Here's some very light debugging info which may expose the problem:

```
$ java -jar HelloWorld.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld


$ jar tvf HelloWorld.jar 
     0 Mon Apr 27 00:57:58 CDT 2015 META-INF/
   113 Mon Apr 27 00:57:58 CDT 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  1014 Mon Apr 27 00:57:58 CDT 2015 HelloWorld$1.class
  1436 Mon Apr 27 00:57:58 CDT 2015 HelloWorld.class




(HwlloWorld.jar  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
Manifest-Version: 1.0
JavaFX-Version: 8.0
Class-Path: 
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

What's missing?

Comment: I just tried it. Works without problems on Win7. Can you zip the entire content of the example folder and put it on the web?

Comment: Thanks for that insight.  Could you run `echo %CLASSPATH%` on your system and share output?  My classpath isn't set which may mean I need to set it in build.xml instead (or try playing with the variable to see if it helps)

Comment: The entire code project is available here  https://github.com/thenotary/helloJavafx

Comment: Well, that works for me on Win7 without problems. I don't have the classpath set. Can you try running the file with java -cp . -jar HelloWorld.jar?

Comment: I get the same output of `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld`

Comment: When you invoked that, you were in the same folder as the helloworld.jar? Because in your github link you write this: "java -jar dist/HelloWorld.jar", ie with "dist". And what's the output of "java -version"? The 1.8.0_45 is in your path, i. e. you start the jar with exactly that java version?

Comment: I tried your code now under RedHat Linux, but with Java 1.7.0_80 since I had no 1.8 available, it worked without problems.

Comment: I'm giving up, too much time invested so far.  I tried setting up on windows 7 as if java picked windows as a primary platform but that was another broken install.  Thanks all for trying, maybe I'll try RHL sometime in the future but don't have ISOs atm for them.

Comment: Why don't you try my approach?

Comment: I think I did, but it didn't have an effect.  Thanks for trying to help though.  I gather this is a problem of setting up an environment properly.  I've got to approach my problem with a different solution,  I only meant to use JVM for it's web view, which can be done by other means.

Comment: Ok mate, I agree with you... there must be something with your environment, because all of the lines in the manifest file was autmatically added, I didn't add any manifest record at jar creating. (+ I used jars from an 1.7x JDK)

Answer (score 4):

The message "Could not find or load main class HelloWorld" means that Java was not able to find the `HelloWorld` class in its classpath. I suspect this may be due to the `Class-Path` entry being empty in the manifest file:

```
Class-Path:
```

You may want to try overriding this entry to set the classpath to the root of the Jar by adding the following in the Ant buildfile (this is similar to the example in [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIACICBG)):

```
<fx:jar destfile="${build.dist.dir}/HelloWorld.jar">
    <fx:application refid="HelloWorldID"/>
    <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>

    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
    </manifest>
</fx:jar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I think you're on to something, but the .JAR output's manifest is still coming up blank for me =(

Answer (score 3):

I have a working ant build for my Javafx application(it's 2.2, but it might work for you), the application is tested on win and linux.
These are the key differences:

```
<path id="fxant">
    <filelist>
        <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
        <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
    </filelist>
</path>

<taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
    uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
    classpathref="fxant"/>
```

Moreover when I check the manifest file, I see something like this:

```
JavaFX-Application-Class: packagename.MainClass
JavaFX-Class-Path: packagename/MainClass.class
```

These are automatically added and I don't have Main-Class and Class-Path.